# Checkbox is not updating model in ngstrap modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

In directive, we have set `$scope.checkValue = true`, and the same scope is passed to ngstrap modal dialog.

below is the code from directive link function which is called on button click and popup the dialog:

```
return {
        templateUrl: "../Views/userSubscriptionView.html",
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        link: function ($scope, element, attributes) {
$scope.checkValue = false; //this is bind to checkbox model but not updating on check/uncheck.
    function DoOpenDialog()
    {
       //other code
        var myOtherModal = $modal({ scope: $scope, templateUrl: "../Views/SubscribePopup.html", show: false , persist:false});
                                myOtherModal.$promise.then(myOtherModal.show);
    }
```

Below is the code from dialog:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkValue"/>
{{checkValue}}
```

The problem is: when I check the checkbox to true or false, model 'checkValue' is not updating. I need to change the state of other control based on the checkbox check state.

Thanks

Comment: post your directive code to help more.

Comment: without more code, it's impossible to know for sure what your issue is, but it is likely that you are having issues due to [JavaScript Prototype Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs).  In general, you should **always use a dot in angular bindings**.

Comment: Updated post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I use to solve this by explicitly setting the `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` properties :

```
<input type="checkbox" 
  ng-true-value="'true'" 
  ng-false-value="'false'" 
  ng-model="checkValue"
/>
```

Notice the single quotes around `'true'`. Ultimately everything is passed as strings, not as booleans or integers. I use the same approach when I have to deal with a boolean (tinyint) 0 / 1 value from mysql: `ng-true-value="'1'"` and so on.